# Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException when calling Webservice in Production environment

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

we have created a webservice in `.NET`. We have deployed it on dev environment with .net framework 4.0. when we are calling from .Net console application and passing parameter it returns the desired output.

BUt when we deployed it on client production environment its giving error as

```
Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function 'GetContractDetails' expects parameter '@CONTRACT_NO', which was not supplied.
```

we are passing parameter to webservice even then webservice is returning above error.

IS it a because of firewall issue on production server or any other reason?

Comment: That's a SQL exception, it has nothing to do with firewalls. Log what parameters come in and debug it.

Comment: yes this is sql exception returned from web service i am calling . Web service internally is connecting to sqlservr database.. Point is why service is returning this error even though i am pasing the required paramter. It seems paramter passed by the client to webservice is not reaching there due to some reason...

Comment: Did you *Log what parameters come in and debug it* ?

Comment: no i haven't log in webservice. However I tried hardcoding paramter in webservice and it returns value to client...... let me try logging parameter comes in at webservice side.. I have hosted webservice on port 8081...could it because this port no is not accepting parameter

Comment: Ports have nothing to do with messages. Either your message can be received at the port, or not. A port is just an address, like a house number. There's either a house there, or there's not. If the delivered package does not contain the chocolate you ordered, the house number of the delivery address has nothing to do with it.

Comment: thanks buddy i have understoood.... just one more point comes to my mind... i have created webservice in .net framework 2.0 and calling it from client - net framework 4.5 .. could this be an issue